# Is it safe/secure to run .format() on user-provided strings in Python?

Tags: python, security

Scenario: An end-user (untrusted) provides a string such as, `"Hello, {name}!"`. On a server, I want to do string substitution on that user-provided string in the form of, `my_string.format(name="Homer")`. There are a great many things you can do with string formatting in Python, so I'm wondering whether it is a security concern to run a `format()` method on an untrusted string. Is it possible to provide a string value that, when Python's string substitution is used, will alter data outside of the string content itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to use python str.format method with user-submitted templates in server-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76783239/is-it-safe-to-use-python-str-format-method-with-user-submitted-templates-in-serv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String formatting is safe in a way that it does not have side effects. It won't change anything outside of that string.

It can still be a security issue depending on what you do with that string later on. The most obvious example is using string formatting for SQL statements; That's horrendously unsafe.

Comment: _String formatting is safe in a way that it does not have side effects. It won't change anything outside of that string._ Unfortunately, this is not completely true. String formatting absolutely can have side effects. Bear in mind that string formatting can perform arbitrary attribute and index lookups, which can trigger a large number of different special methods, any of which could potentially have side effects.

Comment: The risks also aren't limited to side effects. User provided format strings can easily leak sensitive information as well. Tricks like `"{obj.method.__globals__[sys].modules[<any imported module>]}"` can allow the user providing the format string to access _any_ loaded module. It's quite easy to make a format string print out all of a server's environment variables or the contents of a configuration module, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76783331/11082165)

Comment: There are also denial of service risks as well. Due to the sheer number of different objects that a format string can interact with, and the variety of special methods that can be called on those objects, there's no telling what sort of weird and unexpected exceptions could be raised or what resource intensive operations that may be performed. Even something as simple as `"{:10000000000}"` could hog massive amounts of memory or crash the process.