# Is it safe to use python str.format method with user-submitted templates in server-side?

Tags: python, security, xss, template-engine

I am working on project where users must be able to submit templates containing placeholders to be later rendered to generate dynamic content.

For example, a user might submit a template like:

`"${item.price} - {item.description} / {item.release_date}"`

that would be after formatted with the real values.

Using a template engine (as Django or Jinja) for this purpose would require a lot of validation and sanitizing to prevent SSTI and XSS, so I was wondering if I could use the python [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method to create a more limited and safer alternative, since this method cannot execute python code directly (I believe).

My question is:

Is using string.format safe enough when dealing with user-submitted templates, or it would still be vulnerable to injection attacks?
If it is not, is there any alternative to implement a "safe template rendering" in python?

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952543/is-it-safe-secure-to-run-format-on-user-provided-strings-in-python)?
The fun thing, there it states it could be safe. And I think I agree when they may provide the string and you provide the format arguments (using `my_str.format(**item)` in your case). There is no way to run code inside the string by code injection, this fails: `strr='this is my hack string {import json}';strr.format(name = 'siete')`, returns a `KeyError: 'import json'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, it is not safe in general to use `str.format` with user-provided format strings.

Format strings *are* capable to executing a limited form of Python code. This limited code is just powerful enough to pose significant denial of service (DOS) and data breach risks.

The main factors that make using untrusted format strings risky are:

1. There's no telling how large the formatted string will be. Even short format strings can lead to *massive* expansions, posing DOS risks.
2. Python's [string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) is actually quite rich, and notably supports *arbitrary indexing and attribute access* on the format arguments.
   This means that you have to worry not only about the objects that you are passing to `str.format`, but also about every object that is *indirectly accessible* from those objects via indexing and attribute lookups.  It turns out that the space of indirectly accessible objects is *very* large.
3. Performing indexing or attribute access operations can trigger [a larger number of different special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). These triggered methods can have unintended side effects or raise unexpected exceptions.

#### Data Breach Risks

Off the top of my head, I came up with this toy example of how `str.format` with a carefully constructed format string can easily leak sensitive information from your server. This attack only relies on the attacker knowing (or guessing) the of types of the arguments being supplied to `str.format`.

Running this code will **print all environment variables** defined on the server:

```
import os

class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        pass

user_format = "{f.foo.__globals__[os].environ}"
print(user_format.format(f=Foo()))
```

Specific to Django, this format string will **print your entire settings module**, complete with your DB passwords, signing keys, and all sorts of other bits of exploitable information:

```
user_format = "{f.foo.__globals__[sys].modules[myapp.settings].__dict__}"
```

#### Denial of Service Risks

Simple format strings like `"{:10000000000}"` can lead to massive memory consumption. This can grind things to a halt due to constant page swapping, or even crash the server process with a `MemoryError` exception or OOM kill.

Additionally, due to the sheer number of different objects that a format string can interact with, and the variety of special methods that can be called on those objects, there's no telling what sort of other weird and unexpected exceptions could be raised or what resource intensive operations that may be performed. You can imagine a scenario where an ORM manager class has a property that triggers a database transaction when accessed. Such a property could be repeatedly accessed in the format string to stall the server with database interactions.

Comment: Interesting. But, suppose that my rendering module itself does not directly import "os", "sys", or any similar module (although they are be imported in other scripts in the project), it would still be possible to exploit this vulnerability? And, what if I run this code with `exec`, limiting the globals?

Comment: @G.Bittencourt: This attack doesn't depend on any globals that could be sandboxed with `exec`, or any of the rendering module's own imports. It only inspects the `format` arguments.

Comment: @G.Bittencourt As for the first part, direct imports aren't needed since indirect imports can also be followed (e.g., if you import `pathlib` in `Foo`'s module, an attack could use `__globals__[pathlib].os` - same goes for any of your modules that are imported). I don't think running it with `exec` would help since it's the "globals" in  `Foo`'s module that matter, not the globals in the execution context of the `str.format` call.

Comment: This is selling your soul, it seems [safe to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952543/is-it-safe-secure-to-run-format-on-user-provided-strings-in-python) when you provide a controlled set of format arguments.